# How can I change logic from (False to True) based on the 1st column and (True to False) based on the 2nd column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-ta

The idea is to switch between the set of True and False conditioned by 2 columns.

For example

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | False | False |
| False | False | False |
| **True** | False | True |
| False | False | True |
| True | False | True |
| True | False | True |
| True | False | True |
| False | False | True |
| False | **True** | False |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | False |
| False | False | False |
| False | True | False |
| **True** | False | True |
| False | False | True |
| False | False | True |

What I would like to generate is the "Column C".

"Column A" changes "Column C" from ("False" to "True").

"Column B" changes "Column C" from ("True" to "False").

Triggering by the First "True"

Answer (score 0):

I finally have the answer to this by making use of cumsum().

```
df['Column A'] = ....
df['Column B'] = ....

df["Cumsum1"] = df['Column A'].cumsum()
df["Cumsum2"] = df["Cumsum1"].where(df["Column B"]).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

df["Column C"] = df["Cumsum1"]-df["Cumsum2"]
df["Column C"] = df["Column C"].replace(df["Column C"].values, 1).where(df["Column C"]!=0, 0).astype(bool)
```

If anyone have the simpler solution, please share. Thanks